# Would one-hot classification allow me to generate error bars of results?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression

I'm currently using a regression ANN to determine the size of an object, in the range [1,100]. I get the output values (sometimes outside of the desired range), but I have no idea how confident the network is of the result.

I'm thinking, if I set up an ANN with a 100 one-hot vector as the output would I be able to determine the most likely result and its confidence? My understanding is that a one-hot classification network gives a number of output values, the sum of which equal 1, so in essence you are getting the probability of each value and can work out some error bars.

Am I way off here, or is there a better way of determining the confidence of the result on a regression ANN?

I should mention that I'm currently using Python 3.5 and Keras with a Tensorflow backend.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the output size of your model is an integer (i.e. $\in\mathbb Z ^{[0,100]}$) a vector $\in \mathbb R^{100}$ should definitely be the output to your ANN. This is the most common approach to creating output classification for neural networks.

The values of this output vector could be all over the place depending on how your weights are initialized/trained so in order to interpret the output as a probability of belonging to one of the given 100 classes (and sum to 1 as you say) you need to feed the output through a [soft max function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function). You can then take the output of this to get your size class prediction and train using the cross entropy.

If your output is continuous the easiest approach is just to have one output size, train on MSE, and get your answer by rounding between 0 and 100.